# How to get exact match of & in the given string

Tags: java, regex

Example: `"True && False & True"`

In the above string I am trying to match if only `&` is present and not looking for consecutive characters (`&`).

I mean `&&` should not be matched but It should match only `&` if it is available in the string.

In the aforementioned case I should get only 1 match since its available.

I am looking for a regular expression.

Tried Options:

```
(?=&{1})
```

I believe by using length of string and finding the first occurrence of `&` and counting the same will give the result.

But still looking for a better answer in form of regular expressions.

Comment: What is the final result you want to achieve? Count or replace? Or just check if  a string does not contain `&&` but contains `&`? Also, in VBScript, you cannot use lookbehinds, thus, a single solution for both is hard to devise without more concrete requirements.

Comment: Instead to search the correct string (those with just one *&*), you could try to look for the wrong ones (those strings with more than *&*).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<!&)&(?!&)
```

This means "An `&` not preceded or followed by another `&`"

Sample Java code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "True && False & True but & is & right?";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!&)&(?!&)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
    // can keep counter and add +1 here
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }

}
```

O/P :

```
&
&
&
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I needed. Thanks and sorry for mentioning java and vb script language. I will be more specific in my future posts.

Answer (score 0):

While using Regex you can take advantage of what we call : Positive and Negative Lookahead or Lookbehind.
This means when you search for a character in a String and you don't want it followed by something else you use Negative Lookahead , positive is the opposite. if you don't want that Character to follow something you use Lookbehind.
Functionally you are lookinf for '&' that is not followed by '&' and that doesn't follow '&'.

You compile your Regex Pattern with the expression :

```
(?<!&)&(?!&)
```